# Issue with systemfonts when loading kableExtra()

Tags: r, kableextra

I'm trying to load `kableExtra` but having issues on Mac. When I install based on Rstudio's prompt to install it, I get this message:

```
In utils::install.packages("systemfonts", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also manually installed it through the environment -> packages and got no errors.

In any case, when I run my code I get this error message:

```
Quitting from lines 12-21 (project_4.Rmd) 
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called 'systemfonts'
Execution halted
```

I've also installed `Xquartz` package based on a recommendation from another SO post. Still didn't help. Please advise.

Comment: Try: ```install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('r-lib/systemfonts')```

Comment: just tried it and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from [there](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/1427) ...

... you should install **[freetype](https://freetype.org)** library.

After that you can install `systemfonts` via `install.packages`.